# I am a Resident Alien for tax purposes. Can I claim exemptions from the India - US Tax Treaty (21)?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am an Indian citizen living in the US since 2008 with an F1 Visa. I am a resident for tax purposes. Can I claim exemption under the India US Tax Treaty (21) "Students and Business Apprentices From India"? So Do I have to file the 1040NR in spite for being a resident alien for tax purposes?

Could anyone site me IRS publications which clarifies this? I am looking through [p519](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p519.pdf) and am lost :-/

Comment: Why are you resident for tax purposes if you're on F1? Five years passed?

Comment: Yes. I have been in the US since 2008

Comment: As a resident, you get a standard deduction of $6300. My feeling is that the treaty allows students from India to avail the same benefits. Claiming the treaty exemptions as a resident would amount to claiming the benefits twice. I think.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find several references that claim that the Indo-US treaty provision is limited to five years:

[Here](https://www.uth.edu/dotAsset/8346471f-9ec3-487f-b370-fb4912a1a6bd.pdf) it says this (on page 20):

> Generally the treaty exemption for students is limited to the first
>   five calendar years that the international student is in the U.S.
>   However there is no set time limit for students from Belgium,
>   Bulgaria, China, The Netherlands, and Pakistan.

However, I couldn't find any specific time limit neither in the treaty nor in the [technical explanation](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/inditech.pdf). The explanation says:

> Thus, for example, an Indian resident who visits the United States as
>   a student and becomes a U.S. resident according to the Code, other
>   than by virtue of acquiring a green card, would continue to be exempt
>   from U.S. tax in accordance with this Article so long as he is not a
>   U.S. citizen and does not acquire immigrant status in the United
>   States. The saving clause does apply to U.S. citizens and immigrants.

However, the treaty explicitly says this:

> The benefits of this Article shall extend only for such period of time
>   as may be reasonable or customarily required to complete the education
>   or training undertaken.

The reason for this last paragraph is to ensure that you don't artificially prolong your student status, and the 5 year limit may come out of the interpretation of this specific paragraph.

Similar paragraph exists in the US-China treaty, and [the explanation](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/chintech.pdf) for that treaty says this:

> These exemptions may be claimed only for the period reasonably
>   necessary to complete the education or training. In some cases, the
>   course of study or training may last less than year. For most
>   undergraduate college or university degrees the appropriate period
>   will be four years. For some advanced degrees, such as in medicine,
>   the required period may be longer, e.g., seven years.

Based on this, it is *my personal impression* that if you're an undergraduate student and studying the same degree (and not, for example, finished your BA, and started your MS) - you are no longer eligible for the treaty benefit.

But I suggest you ask a professional (EA/CPA licensed in your State) for a more reliable tax advice on the matter. I'm not a tax professional and this is not a tax advice.